# Can a pirated Mac OS on a virtual machine publish games to iOS store?

Tags: ios, macos

So I'm working with a client and finished creating a game for android using Clickteam Fusion 2.5. Now at this point he wants to deploy it also to the IOS App Store. I told him that he would have to get a mac pc in order to do that.

Am i correct?

I have already given him the game and source code. Would he be able to do that?

Comment: I guess he would probably need a valid macOS to request a certificate for signing the code objects, as well as be a bonafide Apple dev-member beholden to the agreements.

Comment: I think from a virtual machine you can upload. Or simply hire someone who has a Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would he be able to do that?

Yes. As long as he has an Apple Developer account, he'll be fine. There are lots of comments and testimonies out there about being able to release applications using hackintosh - means no problem with code signing at all. [Reference.](https://www.reddit.com/r/hackintosh/comments/939pmo/is_xcode_running_fine_in_hackintosh/)

Comment: Using a pirate os means that’s not going to be an apple dev.